# Acerola Supporter card effect

Tags: pokemon

> Put 1 of your pokemon that has any damage counters on it and all cards attached to it into your hand.

Does this mean I can move my active pokemon which has damage on it straight into my hand?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that is exactly the point.  Sometimes this is just a free heal - sometimes it’s useful to for example play a Tapu Lele or Dedenne another time, or even reuse an ability that was already used that turn (when the Pokémon leaves the zone of play, it no longer is that same Pokémon essentially and can reuse its ability so long as it’s not a ‘only one of X ability can be used per turn’ ability).

Note that if you do this and have no Pokémon on your bench, you lose!

Comment: I shouldve added also "as well as any benched pokemon" as this would indicate that I understand how the card works but wasnt sure if it also included my active pokemon. Thanks for that, what a nice little supporter she is then! :)